# Strat new Activity some time Creare error as 272097-byte external allocation too large for this process

Tags: android

I have Tab Based Application and in between application i change tab some time error will generate as "272097-byte external allocation too large for this process." and Application will Crash.. so how can handle this error and Continue my application without crash? is there any method?

Answer (score 0):

You run out of memory. That is why your application crashes.

You said that the error appears when you switch the tab some times. This looks to me like a memory leak. You should watch logcat on messages like:

```
GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 10413K/10631K, paused 2ms+2ms
```

It says that your application uses 10 MB memory. When you switch tabs watch this number. When it does not go down again then you have a memory leak.

Some cause may be that you created Views with the application context. By this the Views cannot be garbage collected since the application context holds a reference to it.

Look here for further information:

- http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk